# magento 1.7 product export page goes blank after long time

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7 for my site when I do export for one sku I easily get csv but when I want to export around 2500 product its goes in infinite loop and sometime I get only blank page.

Checking my system log file I get this:

Notice: Undefined index: 0  in /chroot/home/utwomobi/u2mobility.com/html/includes/src/Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product.php on line 663